# Why is this CASE statement in my T-SQL query not working properly?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, sql-like

I am running the following T-SQL code in `SSMS` but I am not getting the result I am expecting regarding the last column in the query:

```
 SELECT *, 
           (CASE WHEN Description like '%AI% '
                 THEN 'AI'
                   ELSE 'OTHER'
                     END) as 'Meal Plan'
 FROM TestTable
```

The 'Description' column from TestTable is an `nvarchar` column. An example of a value in that column would be 'STD AI REVENUE'.

From the query above, I expect the value of the 'Meal Plan' column to be 'AI' if the corresponding value in the Description column is 'STD AI REVENUE'. However, my query is filling the whole 'Meal Plan' column with 'OTHER'.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is your current logic:

```
CASE WHEN Description like '%AI% '
```

This will match descriptions *ending* in a space.  You probably intend to do this:

```
CASE WHEN Description like '%AI%'
```

Here is a demo showing the logic behind your query and my suggested correction:

## Rextester

Comment: Oh dear! Typing error! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps you intended this: `CASE WHEN Description like '%AI %'` ... with a space _before_ the wildcard.

Comment: You just gave me a brilliant idea! Thanks again!

Comment: or `% AI %` spaces before and after? but then it can't start or end with just AI (no preceeding or trailing space) to be included.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
CASE WHEN Description like  N'%AI% '
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should look like'%AI %', not '%AI% ' (note where the space is),
and as just mentioned above you should use *unicode* search string with unicode field even if in your particular case it doesn't matter